# Trouble passing down redundant arguments

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have the SQLite3 gem, and I can only initialize it once for a database. Say I have `method1` that calls `method2` ten times, which calls `method3` twenty times, which needs to access the SQLite database and update some records. I'll end up with 100+ instances of SQLite3 if I initialize it inside `method3`. Method1, method2 and method3 are all in different classes.

I solved it by creating new instance at the top level, and then passing it down to `method1`, then to `method2` and `method3`. This is unsustainable because if I do this with two or three more arguments (say I have three more databases that `method3` will update), there will be a lot of redundant arguments.

How do I solve this? Some ideas are creating a global variable or a constant that will start upon the initialization of the program. Another, overwrite the `new` method. I don't know the advantages and the drawbacks of each. If you know other approaches, or the pros/cons/viability of the two above, let me know.

Here's an example code:

```
require 'sqlite3'

class A
  db = SQLite3::Database.new('somename.sqlite')

  def call_other_method
    B.new.other_method
  end
end

class B
  def other_method
    C.new.other_method_2
  end
end

class C
  def other_method_2
    # I want to call here methods on db, without passing it as an arg, first 
    # to call_other_method, then to other_method and then to other_method_2
  end
end

A.new.call_other_method
```

Comment: The [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is what you are asking for.

Comment: Install `ActiveRecord` gem (it can be used outside of rails) and your life will get easier.

Comment: Can you post some code you've tried in order to solve your question?

Comment: @mudasobwa what's the advantage of using 1 instance (where I'll have to overwrite .new) vs. storing one instance in a constant and then calling that constant from whenever I need from?

Comment: Is there a reason to have these different classes and to instantiate one class from within another?

Comment: I'm using the page object pattern to go to various pages. Then another class that connects the actual web pages with the database class (depending on what the page object methods return). The database is also its own class. And then another class that makes use of the 'connector' class and where the actual database is initialized. So in my example it's 2, not 3 levels deep, but my methods get all messy because I have 3 instances of sqlite3, and they'll be the ONLY instances in the entire app, and don't want to pass them redundantly when I have to make use of them.

Comment: So basically with the way it is right now I have to pass the db in the 'main' class that makes use of everything down to the 'connector' class and then down to the 'database' class. It's 3 levels down just like in the example and it isn't pretty with so many redundant args.

Comment: @daremkd While you project consists of 100 code lines, there is [almost] no advantages. Actually, using constant is a poor implementation of singleton pattern. As soon as your codebase growth, you’ll find youself creating new instances “_just because_.” Which in fact will ruin your pattern. Plus your global constant should be initialized in the very beginning (tomorrow this codepart will be in the middle in init process,) while calling `Factory::inst` is safe whereever.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
module Sqlite3Connection
  require 'sqlite3'

  def self.connection
    @@db ||= SQLite3::Database.new('somename.sqlite')
  end
end

require 'sqlite3_connection'
class SQLite3Record
  include Sqlite3Connection

  attr_reader :db

  def initialize
    @db = SQLite3Connection.connection
  end

end

class A < SQLite3Record

  def call_other_method
    # did you mean this?:
    10.times{ B.new.other_method }
    # or?:
    # b = B.new
    # 10.times { b.other_method }
  end
end

class B < SQLite3Record

  def other_method
    # did you mean this?:
    20.times{ C.new.other_method_2 }
    # or?:
    # c = C.new
    # 20.times { c.other_method2 }
  end
end

class C < SQLite3Record

  def other_method_2
    # will be called 200 times!
    # will have single instance of "SQLite3::Database" here accessible via method db.
    db.execute(sql)
  end
end

A.new.call_other_method
```